# Creating namespaces in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, namespaces

I'm kind of new to JavaScript. I have a bunch of utility functions I've written over the years in C#. I'd like to migrate some of them to JavaScript. When I use them in code, as a developer, I'd like to make the following call:

```
myCompany.myLibrary.functionName(param1, param2, etc);
```

My question is, how do I set this up in JavaScript? For instance, at this time, I have:

```
var functionName = function() {
  // do stuff
};
```

However, I'm not sure how to 'scope' that into myCompany.myLibrary. Is this type of thing possible. I think it is. I'm basing this off of libraries like lodash. However, as I'm kind of new to JavaScript, I might be incorrect in my interpretation.

Thank you for any help you can provide.

Comment: There are no namespaces, what you want is just an object accessed with dot notation.

Comment: See if this helps https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Values,_variables,_and_literals

Comment: Look into AMD modules rather than simply namespacing your code. There are far more benefits.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just another way how you could organize your JavaScript library (and have your own namespace at the same time).

```
var myCompany = myCompany || {};

myCompany.myLibrary = (function() {

    var myPrivateProperty = "I'm a private property.";
    var myPrivateMethod = function () {
    // I'm a private method
    }

    return {
        myPublicProperty: "I'm a public property.",
        myPublicMethod1: function () {
        // I'm a public method
        },
        myPublicMethod2: function (arg1, arg2) {
            // I'm a public method, capable to return/call private property or method 
            return myPrivateProperty; 
        }
    };
})();
```

Usage:

```
myCompany.myLibrary.myPublicProperty;    
myCompany.myLibrary.myPublicMethod1();
myCompany.myLibrary.myPublicMethod2(x,y);
```

Answer (score 1):

With the code below you can extend the "namespace" from different files. I believe this is called the module pattern.

```
var myCompany;
(function (myCompany) {
    (function (myLibrary) {
        myLibrary.someFunction = function () {
        };
    })(myCompany.myLibrary || (myCompany.myLibrary = {}));
    var myLibrary = myCompany.myLibrary;
})(myCompany || (myCompany = {}));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var myCompany = {
    myLibrary1: {
        func1: function (param1, param2, etc) {...},
        func2: function (param1, etc) {...},
        prop1: 7,
        prop2: 'xyz'
    },
    myLibrary2: {
        func1: function () {...},
        prop1: 123.0004
    }
};
```

Then you can:

```
myCompany.myLibrary1.func1(1, 2, 3);
myCompany.myLibrary2.prop1 = 'hello world';
```

Answer (score 0):

I like the approach where you have a "namespace" function that takes the string "myCompany.myLibrary" in your case and creates that object structure (if it doesn't exist) and returns a reference to the object:

```
namespace('myCompany.myLibrary').functionName = function(){}
```

You can find an example of how the namespace function could be written here: http://elegantcode.com/2011/01/26/basic-javascript-part-8-namespaces/